# How can i get PUT parameters in module.php file of zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, put, http-method

I want to get a PUT parameters in module.php in zend Framework 2. here is the code snippet i have using to get but i am getting empty array in results.

Code is as follows,

```
parse_str($request->getContent(), $requestParams);
$requestParams=$storeResponse->setVariable("data", $requestParams)->serialize();
```

This works for me for DELETE method but not working for PUT method.

thanks in advance !